# В Brackets не работает Live Preview, нужно обновлять страницу браузера, что изменения вступили в силу

Tags: adobe-brackets

В **Brackets** не работает *Live Preview*, кто то сталкивался с этим? как это решить?
вношу изменения в коде, а они не отображаются автоматически. Только если обновить страницу браузера.

Comment: В каком браузере вы работете? Live Preview работает только с Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если я правильно понял, *Live Preview* в **Brackets** работает только если **HTML** файл был создан в редакторе.

Comment: Нет, Live Preview работает с любым HTML файлом, не зависимо от того в каком редакторе он был создан.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы всё работало, в боковой панели нужно открыть директорию с сайтом/проектом.

Answer (score 1):

В моём случае, проблема решилась временным назначением браузера Chrome по-умолчанию. После вернул Opera обратно. Дальше редактор уже находил браузер Chrome нормально.
 До этого, редактор Brackets, так и ругался, что не мог найти Chrome в системе Windows.

*PS: Вопрос хоть и старый, но находится в топе Google, по-этому написал здесь*

Answer (score 0):

Live Preview работает только с Google Chrome. Перестает работать если в браузере вызваны инструменты разработчика по `Ctrl-Shift-I` или `F12`. Чтобы Live Preview снова заработал нужно просто опять в Brackets при выбранном HTML файле нажать `Ctrl-Alt-P` либо же кликнуть мышкой по значку молнии на боковой панели в правом верхнем углу редактора.

Answer (score 0):

Надо в меню Brackets Отладка вызвать Перезагрузить с расширениями F5

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста поподробнее, что даст ваше решение?

Answer (score 0):

Просто запусти хром в соседнем с редактором окне, а встроенное окно просмотра в самом редакторе закрой. И будет тебе счастье...